# Keyboard input for 2D Text Box

Tags: java, input, textbox, lwjgl

So I've been stuck with this problem for the past day and half.
I am trying to implement a 2D writeable text-box in my LWJGL game. The rendering of the text box is not a problem, and works flawlessly.

My input, however isn't really working that well. The problem is that I can't figure out how to detect single key presses, so instead of adding "a" to my input string, it adds: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", since the game clock is pretty fast.

This is my code:

```
private boolean canType = false;

private static long curTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
private static long keyTypeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
String input = "";

// Game loop
// I'm using a timer to limit typing, which doesn't work that well.

        if (curTime - keyTypeTime >= 100) {
            keyTypeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            canType = true;

        }

        if (canType) {
            char c = Keyboard.checkAllKeys();
            canType = false;
            if (c != '*') {
                if (c == '/') {
                    System.out.println("backspace");
                    if (input != null && input.length() > 0) {
                        input = input.substring(0, input.length() - 1);
                    }
                } else if (c == '{') {
                    storyLogic();
                } else {
                    input += c;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my actual keyboard class, and the "checkAllKeys" method:

```
package me.mateo226.main;
```

import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWKeyCallback;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;

public class Keyboard extends GLFWKeyCallback{

```
public static boolean[] keys = new boolean[65536];

// The GLFWKeyCallback class is an abstract method that
// can't be instantiated by itself and must instead be extended
// 
@Override
public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    keys[key] = action != GLFW_RELEASE;
}

// boolean method that returns true if a given key
// is pressed.
public static boolean isKeyDown(int keycode) {
    return keys[keycode];
}

public static char checkAllKeys() {
    char key = '*';
    if(isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_A)) {
        key = 'a';
    }
    if(isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_Z)) {
        key = 'z';
    }
    if(isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_SPACE)) {
        key = ' ';
    }
    if(isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_BACKSPACE)) {
        key = '/';
    }
    if(isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_ENTER)) {
        key = '{';
    }


    return key;

}
```

}

Im still learning LWJGL 3 so the keyboard class isn't mine, only the checkAllKeys method is made by me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
string key2 = null;
public static char checkAllKeys() {
    char key = '*';
    if(isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_A)) {
        key2 = 'a';
    }
    if(isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_Z)) {
        key2 = 'z';
    }
    if(isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_SPACE)) {
        key2 = ' ';
    }
    if(isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_BACKSPACE)) {
        key2 = '/';
    }
    if(isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_ENTER)) {
        key2 = '{';
    }

     if(!isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_A)&&key2=='a') {
        key = 'a';
        key2 = null;
    }
    if(!isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_Z)&&key2=='z') {
        key = 'z';
        key2 = null;
    }
    if(!isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_SPACE)&&key2==' ') {
        key = ' ';
        key2 = null;
    }
    if(!isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_BACKSPACE)&&key2=='/') {
        key = '/';
        key2 = null;
    }
    if(!isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_ENTER)&&key2=='{') {
        key = '{';
        key2 = null;
    }
}
```